# Use App.config with a Custom Section shared between two different projects

Tags: c#, .net, windows, app-config

## Scenario

I have developed a windows service which is configured by its App.config file.
This file contains the information in the standard sections (**connectionStrings**, **appSettings**) and in a custom section (**sourceTabSection**). 
In the windows service project i have 4 classes which allow me to get/set the config file content. They are based on what is written in this article: [Writing a Custom ConfigurationSection to handle a Collection](http://www.abhisheksur.com/2011/09/writing-custom-configurationsection-to.html) and i have no problems on using them inside my service. 
The problems come when i try to get/set the custom section (with the standard sections i don't have any problems) of the App.config, belong to the Windows service, using another application that in my case is a Windows Form that allows users to view/set parameters for the windows service.
The Windows Form application has the same pack of 4 classes used by the service, in order to handle the App.config.
When the code that get/set custom parameters of Windows Service is excuted on the Windows Form app I get the following error message:

> {"An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for sourceTabSection: Could not load type 'DataReportingService.CustomSourceTabSection.SourceTabSection' from assembly 'DataReportingService'."}

The problem is due to this following line of code in the App.config

`<section name="sourceTabSection" type="DataReportingService.CustomSourceTabSection.SourceTabSection, DataReportingService"/>`

The attribute type of the tag shown above has the following meaning (it's explained here: [section Element for configSections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228245(v=vs.100).aspx)):

`type="Fully qualified class name, assembly file name, version, culture, public key token"`

Following what is written on **Writing a Custom ConfigurationSection to handle a Collection** article I defined only the first two parameter (Fully qualified class name, assembly file name) of the attribute type. Microsoft documentation (no more maintained) doesn't specify that the other parameters can be not defined, but the example that I followed and others use this approach.
However the point is this phrase about the type attribute on Microsoft documentation:

> The assembly file must be located in the same application directory

So, due to this bond, seems to be impossible to handle custom section of an application A from another application B (which has another assembly) using this approach.

So do you know how could I solve this problem?

### Windows service - App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="sourceTabSection" type="DataReportingService.CustomSourceTabSection.SourceTabSection, DataReportingService"/>  
  </configSections>

  <!-- *** CUSTOM SECTION *** -->
  <sourceTabSection>
    <Tables>
      <sourceTab name="TEST" db_conn_str="****"
        keep_time="1" scan_frequency_process_rows="1" 
        scan_frequency_delete_processed_rows="1" />
      <sourceTab name="TEST_2" db_conn_str="****"
        keep_time="1" scan_frequency_process_rows="1" 
        scan_frequency_delete_processed_rows="1" />
    </Tables>
  </sourceTabSection>

  <!-- *** STANDARD SECTIONS *** -->

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DB_Target" connectionString="Data Source=192.168.2.2;Initial Catalog=PlantDompe;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=Gf6swML0MXiqbOFuvRDvdg==;"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="TAB_ALARMS_TARGET" value="AlarmsProcess" />
    <add key="TAB_VALUE_TARGET" value="USER_CHANGES" />
    <add key="TAB_LOGINS_TARGET" value="USER_LOGONS" />
    <add key="LOG_DIR" value="C:/Users/rossi/Documents/Visual Studio 2017/Projects/DRS_proj/Log/" />
  </appSettings>

<startup>
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2" />
</startup>
<system.web>
    <trust level="Full" />
    <webControls clientScriptsLocation="/aspnet_client/{0}/{1}/" />
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

## Ugly solution

If found a work around to this problem by performing the two following steps on the Windows Form application that need to view/set the parameters (custom and no custom) inside the App.config of the Windows Service:

1. Using visual studio i go to Solution Properties > Application tab, and I change the following values
   Assembly name = DataReportingService
   Default namespace = DataReportingService
   **Note:** DataReportingService is the name of the window service with the App.config file
2. Find and replace all the references to old namespace with the new one

In this way I can handle the custom section of the App.config, but honestly it's a really ugly solution and I think that there should be something better.

Comment: From the WinForm app, just treat the app.config as a normal XML file.  Write code using classes like `XDocument` to read/write the XML - don't try to use this app.config as _the WinForm app's_ settings.

Comment: Why not split the handler (SourceTabSection) in its own project which you can use in both solutions (along with any other potentially shareable code maybe).

Comment: @kennyzx Thank you for your quick answer. I've already thought about your solution, but in that case I should implement my XML parser for my custom object instead of using the classes that I've already wrote based on  System.Configuration lib. So I would like to avoid this approach if it's possible and continue to use the classes that I used in the window service.

Comment: @AlexPaven Do you mean to import the 4 classes that I wrote as a dll in both projects? In this case the section element in the App.config should be changed like that: <section name="sourceTabSection" type="**DLL_Root.CustomSourceTabSection.SourceTabSection**, **DLL_Assembly_Name**"/> Am i wrong?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @AlexPaven Your comment has helped me to find the solution, thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Alex Paven, your comment has helped me to solve this problem!
Here below there are the detailed steps of what I've done:

1. I moved the 4 classes which handles the Windows service config file in a Class Library project (.NET Framework) called: DRS_CustomConfig.
2. I changed the namespace of the 4 classes with the following value: **DRS_CustomConfig** and then I compiled the project.
3. I linked the external library both in the Windows service project and in Windows Form application
4. For each class of both projects which need to use the classes contained in the external library I inserted the following piece of code:

   ```
   using DRS_CustomConfig;
   ```
5. In the App.config of the Windows service I changed the section element as follows:

#### Old

```
        <section name="sourceTabSection" 
    type="DataReportingService.CustomSourceTabSection.SourceTabSection, 
    DataReportingService"/>
```

#### New

```
        <section name="sourceTabSection" 
    type="DRS_CustomConfig.SourceTabSection, DRS_CustomConfig"/>
```